# Remove list items from select menu with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design

I have a tiny bit of script that allows the user to resize the window to convert an unordered list into a select menu.

However, I'd like to remove any nested unordered lists from the select menu.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/k7272/

So basically using the example above, the part 'test' wouldn't appear in the select menu, but would still appear in unordered list.

How do I achieve this?

Here is my Javascript:

```
// DOM ready
     $(function() {

      // Create the dropdown base
      $("<select />").appendTo("nav");

      // Create default option "Go to..."
      $("<option />", {
         "selected": "selected",
         "value"   : "",
         "text"    : "Go to..."
      }).appendTo("nav select");

      // Populate dropdown with menu items
      $("nav a").each(function() {
       var el = $(this);
       $("<option />", {
           "value"   : el.attr("href"),
           "text"    : el.text()
       }).appendTo("nav select");
      });

       // To make dropdown actually work
       // To make more unobtrusive: http://css-tricks.com/4064-unobtrusive-page-changer/
      $("nav select").change(function() {
        window.location = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
      });

     });
```

Many thanks :-D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

targeting `nav a` will find all its children and even children of children, so you need to directly target them like this

`$("nav > ul > li > a").each(...`

http://jsfiddle.net/k7272/1/

Answer (score 1):

Change the selector to only look for direct children, this will avoid the nested `ul`. Try this:

```
$("nav > ul > li > a").each(function () {
    // your code...
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/k7272/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the "nav a" selector, which selects any  descendant of , use the child operator: $("nav>ul>li>a").

Better yet, put a class on your top level ul and then use $('ul.classname>li>a'), then you can move the whole list around your DOM and still have the selector work.